# RAID 5 virtual disk still shows up as degraded after repair

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, raid5, storage-spaces, virtual-disk, degraded

On a machine running Windows Server 2012 R2, I have a virtual disk consisting of 8 physical disks in a RAID-5 configuration. One drive died, so I replaced the dead drive and followed these instructions for repairing the virtual disk: [Replacing a Failed Disk in Windows Server 2012 R2 Storage Spaces with PowerShell](https://hodgkins.io/replace-failed-disk-in-storage-spaces-pool-with-powershell).

Everything seemed to be working great, with one discrepancy: despite completing the whole repair process with no errors, the virtual disk still is marked as "degraded", even though it once again has 8 healthy drives. What gives?

The file system on the virtual drive (which is backed up) is still accessible, but I'd like to know if I again have resiliency against a drive failure or not, but I can't find any information about why the virtual disk is still degraded, or how to determine if it really is degraded, or how to fix it.

Here is some powershell output that I hope will be useful. Thank you!

[image: Powershell output - see text copy below]

And again as text:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-StoragePool

FriendlyName            OperationalStatus       HealthStatus            IsPrimordial            IsReadOnly
------------            -----------------       ------------            ------------            ----------
Z                       OK                      Healthy                 False                   False
Primordial              OK                      Healthy                 True                    False


PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-VirtualDisk

FriendlyName        ResiliencySettingNa OperationalStatus   HealthStatus        IsManualAttach                     Size
                    me
------------        ------------------- -----------------   ------------        --------------                     ----
Z                   Parity              Degraded            Warning             False                          25.46 TB


PS C:\Users\Administrator> $zdisk = Get-VirtualDisk | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -eq 'Z' }
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk -VirtualDisk $zdisk

FriendlyName        CanPool             OperationalStatus   HealthStatus        Usage                              Size
------------        -------             -----------------   ------------        -----                              ----
PhysicalDisk5       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk1       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk2       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk7       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk6       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk8       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk3       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk4       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     3.64 TB


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

In case it matters, PhysicalDisk4 is the new replacement disk that I added to replace the dead disk.

Note that I'm [cross-posting this from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1482744/virtual-disk-still-shows-up-as-degraded-after-repair) after waiting a while for answers. Not sure if that's against protocol around here - I'll delete the other post if that's the done thing.

Comment: I think it really fit there, but on my side lacking the info to answer you. My guess is it’s still in rebuilding state, but a guess.

Comment: What is the ouptup of Get-StorageJob ?

Comment: Yeah, I monitored the rebuild with Get-StorageJob until it reached 100%. Now Get-StorageJob outputs nothing.